# Java transparent panels & custom effect on panels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, transparent

I want to have transparent panels in my GUI (if like Windows 7 window headers, it is better).

Before I have used `com.sun.awt.AWTUtilities` as

```
AWTUtilities.setWindowOpacity(frame, (float)0.90);
```

but its parameter is a window like `JFrame` and couldn't be used for `JPanel`.

Also I want to have effects on `JPanel` or `JLabel` for example luminescence, as is on Windows 7 header buttons. Any other interesting effect is also helpful for me.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see the tutorials *[How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)* and* [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/)*. Follow the links to excellent example depots by [@camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718042/how-to-make-the-awt-component-transparent-on-progressive-background-image-used-w).

For example,

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;

public class ButtonTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ButtonTest().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton opaqueButton1;
    private JButton opaqueButton2;
    private SoftJButton softButton1;
    private SoftJButton softButton2;

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        opaqueButton1 = new JButton("Opaque Button");
        opaqueButton2 = new JButton("Opaque Button");
        softButton1 = new SoftJButton("Transparent Button");
        softButton2 = new SoftJButton("Transparent Button");
        opaqueButton1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        softButton1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10));
        frame.add(opaqueButton1);
        frame.add(softButton1);
        frame.add(opaqueButton2);
        frame.add(softButton2);
        frame.setSize(567, 350);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Timer alphaChanger = new Timer(30, new ActionListener() {

            private float incrementer = -.03f;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                float newAlpha = softButton1.getAlpha() + incrementer;
                if (newAlpha < 0) {
                    newAlpha = 0;
                    incrementer = -incrementer;
                } else if (newAlpha > 1f) {
                    newAlpha = 1f;
                    incrementer = -incrementer;
                }
                softButton1.setAlpha(newAlpha);
                softButton2.setAlpha(newAlpha);
            }
        });
        alphaChanger.start();
        Timer uiChanger = new Timer(3500, new ActionListener() {

            private LookAndFeelInfo[] laf = UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels();
            private int index = 1;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf[index].getClassName());
                    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
                } catch (Exception exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
                index = (index + 1) % laf.length;
            }
        });
        uiChanger.start();
    }

    public static class SoftJButton extends JButton {
        private static final JButton lafDeterminer = new JButton();
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private boolean rectangularLAF;
        private float alpha = 1f;

        public SoftJButton() {
            this(null, null);
        }

        public SoftJButton(String text) {
            this(text, null);
        }

        public SoftJButton(String text, Icon icon) {
            super(text, icon);

            setOpaque(false);
            setFocusPainted(false);
        }

        public float getAlpha() {
            return alpha;
        }

        public void setAlpha(float alpha) {
            this.alpha = alpha;
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g) {
            java.awt.Graphics2D g2 = (java.awt.Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha));
            if (rectangularLAF && isBackgroundSet()) {
                Color c = getBackground();
                g2.setColor(c);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            }
            super.paintComponent(g2);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateUI() {
            super.updateUI();
            lafDeterminer.updateUI();
            rectangularLAF = lafDeterminer.isOpaque();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very good effects, But if you could suggest me a technique to make panels (not buttons) transparent it was so good for me. I tested this method for JPanels but `super(text, icon);` constructor doesn't work for SoftJPanel.

Comment: @sajad `super(text, icon);` is constructor for `JButton`, place here JLabel, that contains Icon/ImageIcon `super(icon);` for more infos http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html and http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

Answer (score 3):

If you have time I recommend you go through this [Filty Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/). By using this book you can learn to create stunning visual and animated effects with Swing and Java 2D. Learn graphics and animation fundamentals as well as advanced rendering techniques.

EDIT: 
To creat transparent panels call

```
setOpaque(false)
```

It'll pass off painting the background to its parent, which may draw its own background.

You can do a screen capture and then use that to paint the background of the panel.

Comment: no sir! I just want to find a sample code for some java visual effects on JPanels.

Comment: I know about setOpaque(). If you look at the picture I attached my question, you may know I mean transparency as there is in windows 7 start menu. thank you\