# AWT custom window shape using transparent image

Tags: java, swing, awt, transparency

I am trying to make a UI using AWT. I want to use only images and transparent components. Right now I cant understand how to make a main window which is supposed to be a PNG image with a custom shape. All the areas that are transparent in the image are replaced with a black color. Here is the code I use:

```
public class Test {
static Image image;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //switch to the right thread

        image = ImageIO.read(Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/images/panel.png").openStream());

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Frame frame = new Frame("Test");
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                frame.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
                frame.add(new BackGround(image,image.getWidth(frame),image.getHeight(frame)));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setSize(image.getWidth(frame), image.getHeight(frame));
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            }
        }
        );
    }
    private static class BackGround extends Component {
        private Image img;
        private int wid, hgt;
        public BackGround(Image img, int wid, int hgt){
            this.img=img;
            this.wid=wid;
            this.hgt=hgt;

        }
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                graphics.drawImage(image,0,0,wid,hgt,0,0,wid,hgt,null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"I am trying to make a UI using awt."` -- Why? Why not at least Swing?

Comment: javafx has transparent frames , i dont thing awt or swing has that provision . you are setting your background as white , which is making the transparent image white

Comment: I dont really care if it is Swing or AWT. As you can see by the code I used SwingUtilities and in fact tried to achieve the same using Swing already

Comment: AWT components don't have a concept of transparency, they are just opaque

Comment: Exactly. You **should** care if you want this to work.

Comment: Id be grateful if someone told me how to achieve it in Swing

Comment: @black Take a look at the links I added to my answer :P

Comment: @SrinathGanesh I doubt AWT does, but Swing defiantly does [How to Create translucent and Shaped Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html).  This can be achieved in Java 6, Update 10+ and Java 7

Comment: look at @MadProgrammer's answer (1+), but more importantly, study up on the tool you want to use. Go to the tutorials as these are things that you're not going to learn in just an hour or two of SO question and answer.

Comment: There are some serious tweaks and work arounds when working with window shapes.  I prefer to simple make a transparent window and component and render my "shape" to something like a `JPanel`, it gives much better results

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992154/java-transparent-panels-custom-effect-on-panels

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18278531/418556) for tips.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWT components don't have a concept of transparency, they are always opaque

Try taking a look at ...

- [How can I smooth my JFrame shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906687/how-can-i-smooth-my-jframe-shape/13906713#13906713)
- [JFrame the same shape as an Image / Program running in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588786/jframe-the-same-shape-as-an-image-program-running-in-background/13594794#13594794)
- [Java Swing: Transparent PNG permanently captures original background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982431/java-swing-transparent-png-permanently-captures-original-background/15983717#15983717)
- [How to Create translucent and Shaped Windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html)

For more examples of using Swing

Comment: reallyyyyyyyy time to create own www site (seems like as you have bunch of free time) something like as camickr or StanislavL, most or description there will by only simple action copy_paste, not jokes

Comment: @mKorbel Yeah, I've thought about doing that my self ;)

Comment: @mKorbel I thought about blogging some of the more interesting questions that I find here...and yes, it would be nice to simply link people back to the blog...

Comment: right, you can see that :-) whatever, atari from dinosaurs ages:-) by Andrew Thompson too

Comment: @mKorbel  Unfortunately due to the ..unusual nature of my hosting, I have had trouble logging in and minimal help from support.  I'd be uploading a few examples there myself, but I've decided I'd pinch SO's method of formatting code using JS.  Brilliant!  Blogs (even SE's own blogging areas!) tend to be ..more problematic for formatting and displaying code nicely.  I had nightmares trying to get the code in [this blog](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) to look anywhere near good, while knocking out the redundant 'white space'!

Comment: @Andrew Thompson `Nit, but in credentials you’re linking to the swing tag, not applet.` - aaaaaach I see :-) brrrrrr, yes, agree :-)